# LDAP Authentication Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, active-directory

Help!  I have no  clue what I am doing here.  I am reworking old C# code and I need to use LDAP for integrated authentication on an intranet.  The user should be completely unaware of this process but what I need is to have the React page contact the express server passing in the users domain id.  From there I need to perform basic authentication then return all the groups that this user is a member of for validation.

I have read numerous tutorials on passport-activediretory and passport-ldap and so on but I am still confused.

What I am looking for is a single function that will run on every call to the API and will return either validation or, if requested, validation and group names the user belongs to.

What is available to make this process very simple.  I looked at passport but to be honest authentication is not my milieu so I am at best uncertain as to how any of it works.

I am hoping that it will be as simple as `app.all("*", functionHere());`
Being very new to node (first project) I really need extensive help, hopefully in small words.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try starting from there ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth

Comment: I looked through it an honestly could not understand what I was looking at.  npmjs.com doesn't really give any good examples or walkthroughs.  It has occurred to me that the first thing I need is the NTLM userID from the browser making the request.  Then if I can figure out how to connect to the domain controller I can use that to authenticate.  I plugged in the code that they gave me but had not idea how to make it fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have switched to a .Net back end which support for LDAP integration without the need to a lot of excess code.

Will move back to Node once the application is finished then port it over.

Comment: Not a genuine answer, just cleaning up old entries